# Trigger a Function from Table Storage in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

In Azure, how can I automatically trigger a function when data is inserted/updated/deleted in table storage?  The data entity from table storage should be the input to the function.  I need to then pass that data to another endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no table [storage trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings?tabs=csharp#overview) available out of the box!

I would recommend you to use the [cosmosdb table API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-table-dotnet) to take advantage of global distribution, automatic indexing and rich quer which also supports [changefeed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed)

Comment: My data is in Azure table storage, not cosmos.

Comment: you can do that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table

Comment: Okay so here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table-input?tabs=csharp  I see you can create a azure function that reads the data from table storage every time message is sent to the queue.  But how does message get sent to queue with every insert/update/delete in table storage?

Comment: There is no table storage trigger available as you could see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings?tabs=csharp#overview thats where i recommended cosmosdb

Comment: ok, that's not possible for me.  I think i'll just have to create an azure function and put it on a schedule.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: "Use Cosmos DB" really isn't a solution to the OP's problem, and the need for Cosmos DB's features and benefits need to be carefully evaluated, especially since Table Storage and Cosmos DB's Table API provide a very different pricing model, scaling model, etc.

Comment: It's a suggestion to consider, (I have mentioned my recommendation, does not mean that OP has to use it)